# SSRS Report Date Format Switching to US in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

We are using SSRS 2014 and developing reports via SQL Data Tools - BI in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 on Windows 7.  In the last four days we have encountered a rather annoying issue when trying to develop any reports that have a date prompt.

hen we go to report preview in VS, and select a date for the parameter from the calendar control that pops up it saves the date in MM/DD/YYYY format. This includes existing reports that have worked fine in VS for years, and new ones we try to add.  For example:

- Preview report with a "start date" parameter Select the date from the
  calendar e.g. today's date 23rd October 2017
- When it closes the date prompt it saves the date as 10/23/2017 which
  is an invalid date in  en-GB format so the report won't run and I get
  an error that the value is invalid for the parameter's type
- If I select a date which could be valid in either MM/DD/YYYY or
  DD/MM/YYYY format, such as 4th October 2017, it saves it as
  04/10/2017 in the preview text box.
- However, it interprets the date as being 10th April if I reopen the
  calendar control to select another date.

We've tried the following:

- Running with the report language as en-GB, and running with this
  blank
- Checked my location / keyboard settings in control panel (these
  are all UK English)
- Retrieving an old version of a report from source control

If I deploy the report to our test server and run in the browwser this issue doesn't occur.
We are a bit out of ideas now, welcome any help please!

Comment: Is your data set query accepting the value as a date or string data type?

Comment: It should accept it as a date, the underlying field is date datatype.  If we choose a date that is still valid if MM and DD are swapped round (e.g. 08/10/2017 could be August or October)" the report runs quite happily but with the wrong date.  As soon as we choose a date that is invalid if MM and DD are swapped round we get the message "an error occured during local report processing. The value provided for the report parameter 'StartDate' is not valid for its type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much discussion with Microsoft, the solution was to upgrade to Data tools for Visual Studio 2015.  This version is unaffected by the issue.  The working theory is something to do with the version of .Net 2012 uses but to be honest we never got any further!

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to determine without seeing all of the details, but based on your description, it sounds like you may have an intermediate conversion to a string datatype somewhere in the query.  SQL Server stores dates without a format, in an internalized number format.  The only way it would throw the error you're describing is if a string conversion has occurred somewhere and the regional/language settings do not match along the way.

You mentioned the report is using date-picker, so the report parameter is correctly configured as a date.  Do you have any expressions on the date parameter that manipulate it in some way prior to passing it to the sql query?

Comment: Thanks for the replies Wes.  There are no expressions on the date parameter.  There are a range of reports affected, some compare the data parameter directly to a date field in the where clause and some compare it to a datetime field cast as a date.  The frustrating thing is this is affecting around a hundred reports which we could previously work with fine in VS without any error.  I'm wondering if a recent windows update to our laptops is the culprit!

Comment: The laptops shouldn't be the cause.  The date parameters value is not dependent on language, only the presentation of a date value is.  However, you may want to check if your servers had an update that affected the regional settings.

Comment: The issue only occurs when previewing reports locally on our laptops within VS 2012 which as I understand it does not use a SQL server to run the report, only SQL data tools(I may be wrong!).  When we deploy the reports and run them on the development server via IE/Chrome they work fine.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I've managed to persaude our IT deptartment to let me raise a case with Microsoft. I'll post the solution back here once resolved.